# Conditional types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-conditional-types

I was wondering if I can have conditional types in TypeScript?

Currently I have the following interface:

```
interface ValidationResult {
  isValid: boolean;
  errorText?: string;
}
```

But I want to remove `errorText`, and only have it when `isValid` is `false` as a **required** property.

I wish I was able to write it as the following interface:

```
interface ValidationResult {
  isValid: true;
}

interface ValidationResult {
  isValid: false;
  errorText: string;
}
```

But as you know, it is not possible. So, what is your idea about this situation?

Comment: Do you mean, when `isValid` is `false`?

Comment: isValid is redundant then. You might as well just have the errorText, and then if errorText is null, there is no error.

Comment: Yes, @MTilsted, you are right, but we have to keep it because of our legacy codes.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

One way to model this kind of logic is to use a union type, something like this

```
interface Valid {
  isValid: true
}

interface Invalid {
  isValid: false
  errorText: string
}

type ValidationResult = Valid | Invalid

const validate = (n: number): ValidationResult => {
  return n === 4 ? { isValid: true } : { isValid: false, errorText: "num is not 4" }
}
```

The compiler is then able to narrow the type down based on the boolean flag

```
const getErrorTextIfPresent = (r: ValidationResult): string | null => {
  return r.isValid ? null : r.errorText
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. And fascinating that the compiler can actually tell that `r` must be of type `Invalid` here.

Comment: This is called discriminated unions. Pretty cool stuff: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions

Answer (score 48):

To avoid creating multiple interfaces which only get used to create a third, you can also alternate directly, with a `type` instead:

```
type ValidationResult = {
    isValid: false;
    errorText: string;
} | {
    isValid: true;
};
```

Comment: What is this syntax called? I want to learn more about what it does and how it works, but I don't even know what to look up!

Answer (score 23):

The [union demonstrated by bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59172570/778430) is how I recommend handling this. Nonetheless, Typescript **does** have something known as “[conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types),” and they can handle this.

```
type ValidationResult<IsValid extends boolean = boolean> = (IsValid extends true
    ? { isValid: IsValid; }
    : { isValid: IsValid; errorText: string; }
);


declare const validation: ValidationResult;
if (!validation.isValid) {
    validation.errorText;
}
```

This `ValidationResult` (which is actually `ValidationResult<boolean>` due to the default parameter) is equivalent to the union produced in bugs’s answer or in [CertainPerformance’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59172678/778430), and can be used in the same manner.

The advantage here is that you could also pass around a known `ValidationResult<false>` value, and then you wouldn’t have to test `isValid` as it would be known to be `false` and `errorString` would be known to exist. Probably not necessary for a case like this—and conditional types can be complex and difficult to debug, so they probably shouldn’t be used unnecessarily. But you could, and that seemed worth mentioning.

Comment: I'm sure these are really helpful at times. But, to me, the syntax looks really nasty.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Eh, it has good consistency with other Typescript coding, and `extends` is the right operator to use. And it has extremely powerful, particularly since you can also use it to dig into types: `type SecondOf<T> = T extends Pair<any, infer U> ? U : never;`.

Comment: @KRyan I've been thinking about that. Does that basically just mean `SecondOf<number>` 'expands' to `Pair<any, number>`? I guess the saying "don't judge a book by it's cover" is pertinent here.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Ah, no; rather the opposite. `SecondOf<Pair<any, number>>` evaluates to `number`. `SecondOf<number>` evaluates to `never`, because `number extends Pair<any, infer U>` is false, as `number` does not extend any `Pair`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach where you don't need the isValid property. Instead we can use the presence or abscence of the `errortext` property as a marker instead. Here is an example:

```
// Empty for now, can always add properties to it
interface Valid{}

interface InValid {
    errorText: string;
}

// sum/union type, the type is either Valid OR InValid
type ValidationResult =  Valid | InValid;

// custom type guard to determine the type of the result
// TS uses this function to narrow down the type to eiter valid or invalid
function checkIfValidResult(result: ValidationResult): result is InValid{
    return result.hasOwnProperty('errorText') ? true : false;
}

// example of using the type guard
function doSomethingWithResult(result: ValidationResult) {
    if (checkIfValidResult(result)) {
        throw new Error(result.errorText);
    } else {
        console.log('Success!');
    }
}

doSomethingWithResult({});
// logs: Success

doSomethingWithResult({errorText:'Oops something went wrong'});
// Throws error: Oops something went wrong
```